# Conditional HTML statements not working as expected

Tags: html, css, asp.net, internet-explorer, conditional-statements

I'm attempting to fix some IE errors with some web pages I've recently created because we have some internal employees who still use old versions of IE.  I'm using visual studio 2019 for IDE.

Referencing an example from [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/), I've applied the following example to the html in an aspx page:

```
<!--[if gte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_IE.css?id=173" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]> <! -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?id=173" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

If I remove the conditionals and only use one style sheet at a time, they each work normally when I set the respective vs 2019 IIS Express web browser to match.  Generally, Chrome and Firefox are working with the style.css alone ... it's just IE/Edge are the ones I'm trying to fix.

I've seen other [example conditionals](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/conditional-statements-not-working/24209) that do not have the last conditional to have "<! -->":

```
<!--[ ... ]> <! -->
```

When I apply "<! -->", the browser session always uses that enclosed html, and when it's not there, neither of my css files are selected into the session.

I thought that when the conditionals were met, only those values in the enclosed if/endif would be selected ... but that's not happening for me for some reason.

If anyone has some suggestions for me to track down, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are testing with the IE 10 or IE 11 browser. That's why you are not able to see the results properly.

**Conditional comments are not supported in IE 10 and IE 11.**

If you want to apply custom CSS for it too then you need to use media queries.

Test code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <%-- Below code is for browsers except IE --%>
    <![if !IE]>
        <link href="css/normal.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <![endif]>
    
     <%-- Below code is for IE 7, IE 8, IE 9 --%>
    <!--[if gte IE 7]>
        <link href="css/ie_specific.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <![endif]-->

    <%-- Below code is for IE 10, IE 11--%>
    <style>
    @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) 
    {
     
        body 
        {
            background-color: red;
        }
    }
    </style
</head>
<body>
   
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h2>Hello... This is sample text</h2>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Test result:

[image]

You can try to change the **Document mode** in the IE 11 browser developer tools to check the results for the older versions of the IE browser.

[image]

I hope above example will help you to clear the confusion. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you Deepak-MSFT!  This was a very clear help to my questions.